# How can I remote into my machine from outside the LAN without touching anything at the router?

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, configuration

I'm looking to remote into my windows 7 machine (looking to connect to terminal services, not just at a command prompt) from outside my LAN but I currently do not have access to my routers admin page to configure any sort of port forwarding or rules.

Does anyone know if/how I can accomplish this?

**Edit: I'm looking for a free solution to do this, if possible.**

Cheers,

Comment: Be sure to get written permission to do this from your IT/HR people as this kind of thing can be a really good way of finding your belongings in a box at some/many companies :)

Comment: Talk to your system administrator. We're not here to help you circumvent security measures imposed by one of our own.

Comment: Ill be going into my home machine using this service. Are there any security/other issues when going FROM a work/other machine?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use logmein
https://secure.logmein.com/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm looking for a free solution - will update the question

Comment: Logmein offers a free version  https://secure.logmein.com/US/products/free/

Comment: I am a happy customer of logmein pro...

Answer (score 0):

windows live mesh will work and its free!

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Live Essentials beta](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-essentials-beta) includes a [Live Sync](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2010/06/10/coming-soon-windows-live-sync-beta.aspx) feature that combines Live Mesh and [Remote Desktop](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-devices-and-sync-remote-connections-what-ui) capabilites. There is a video on Channel 9 with more information on [Windows Live Sync](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/NicFill/An-Introduction-to-Windows-Live-Sync-and-How-to-Migrate-from-Live-Mesh/) and how it differs from Live Mesh.

Answer (score 0):

From the same folks who give you the (free) LogMein, check out [LogMeIn Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/). Slick little "hosted" (brokered may be a better term) VPN solution that makes it very easy for you to get to your PCs regardless of the firewalls in between them.

I've been using it for years for just what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I've used OpenVPN for this in the past.  Set up an OpenVPN tunnel outwards from the PC you want to access to a machine somewhere (like a VPS) that you do have access to.  I'd then set ssh from the machine I'm at to the open/3rd machine and forward a port (like 3000) to the behind-the-router machine's VPN IP, and connect RDP to localhost:3000.

Machine-behind-router ---OpenVPN--> VPS-or-something <---- Some-client-you're-at

Answer (score 0):

[GoToMyPC](https://www.gotomypc.com) works much in the same way, and is really easy to install at both ends (remote host and the client) as everything works over port 80, which is more-often-than-not the default port available.

They also have a decent 30-day trial of it too.  Give it a whirl.